# xslt compute value based on date

Tags: xslt

Good Day,

I have an xml file that looks like:

```
<albums xmlns="http://www.someurl.com/schema">
    <album>
        <artist>Rush</artist>
        <name>Moving Pictures</name>
        <releaseDate>05-31-1981</releaseDate>
    <album>
</albums>
```

what I want is to use xlst to display the artist, name, and how many years is been since the release date.

```
<div id="recordInfo">
    <div class="col"><xsl:value-of select="/t:albums/t:album/t:artist"></div>
    <div class="col"><xsl:value-of select="/t:albums/t:album/t:name"></div>
    <!-- I want the value of 31 here -->
</div>
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to do that in XSLT?

TIA,

coson

Comment: coson, This needs explanation -- if today is 01-01-2013, and the release date is 12-31-2012, Do you really want the result to be 1 year? This might seem weird, as the real duration is in fact just one day.

Comment: Dimitre, that's an excellent point that I did not take into account when I posted this question.  Most of the data that I'm working with will be at least two years old. However, in this case, the value would be 0.

Comment: Dimitre, one further point, the following url helped me solve my problem because I'm using XSLT 1.0.  http://geekswithblogs.net/lszk/archive/2011/08/24/using-custom-functions-in-xsl.aspx

Comment: Yes, but this is the *xslt* tag and we want to give you a *pure* xslt solution, and not use extension functions. Believe me, in most cases (even in XSLT 1.0) pure solutions exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vTokens" select="tokenize(/*, '-')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vDate" select=
     "string-join(($vTokens[3], $vTokens[1], $vTokens[2]), '-')"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:sequence select=
     "floor((current-date() - xs:date($vDate)) div xs:dayTimeDuration('P365D')) "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>05-31-1981</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
31
```

Comment: Unfortunately, while this does what I want, I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional which is still bound to XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @coson, It may be possible to provide an XSLT 1.0 solution -- however I need that you define the question better. Should the number of months be rounded so that 6months is rounded to one year and 5 months is rounded to 0 years?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an XSLT 2.0 option...

**XML Input**

```
<albums xmlns="http://www.someurl.com/schema">
    <album>
        <artist>Rush</artist>
        <name>Moving Pictures</name>
        <releaseDate>05-31-1981</releaseDate>
    </album>
</albums>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:t="http://www.someurl.com/schema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="albums">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="t:album">
        <div id="recordInfo">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="t:artist|t:name">
        <div class="col"><xsl:value-of select="."/></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="t:releaseDate">
        <xsl:variable name="vOrigDate" select="tokenize(.,'-')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vDate" select="xs:date(concat($vOrigDate[3],'-',$vOrigDate[1],'-',$vOrigDate[2]))" as="xs:date"/>
        <div class="col"><xsl:value-of select="floor(days-from-duration(current-date() - $vDate) div 365)"/></div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<div id="recordInfo">
   <div class="col">Rush</div>
   <div class="col">Moving Pictures</div>
   <div class="col">31</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, while this does what I want, I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional which is still bound to XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT 1.0 template...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:t="http://www.someurl.com/schema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl t" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="current-year" select="2012" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <r>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="t:albums/t:album" />
  </r> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="t:album">
  <div id="recordInfo">
    <div class="col"><xsl:value-of select="t:artist" /></div>
    <div class="col"><xsl:value-of select="t:name" /></div>
    <div class="col"><xsl:value-of select="$current-year - substring(t:releaseDate,7)" /></div>
  </div> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...will yield this output...

```
<r>
  <div id="recordInfo">
    <div class="col">Rush</div>
    <div class="col">Moving Pictures</div>
    <div class="col">31</div>
  </div>
</r>
```

I've used a variable to store the date. In practice you will use a function to get the current date. Which function depends on XSLT version and engine.

Comment: Sean, it is likely that only taking into account the year component of the dates would not produce good result in some cases.